# What is the purpose of base classes in Python if you're already referring to the implementation classes consistently

Tags: python, oop

I have a bunch of python classes that are responsible for validating files like so:

- java file validator
- html file validator
- css file validator
- javascript file validator

All of these classes define a `validate_file(path)` and `validate_string(string)` function.

In the client code of my application, I store all of these validators in an array and I iterate through all of them and call the methods on them in exactly the same way.

Is there a purpose in my case of defining a base "validator" class which defines these methods as abstract? How can I benefit from making these individual classes adhere to the base class? Or maybe in other words, what features would be unlocked if I had a base class with all of these validators implementing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ever write code that needs to process mixed types, some of which might define the API method, but which *shouldn't* be considered "validators", having a common base class for "true" validators might be helpful for checking types ahead of time and only processing the "true" validators, not just "things that look like validators". That said, the more complex the method name, the less likely you are to end up with this sort of confusion; the odds of a different type implementing a really niche method name by coincidence are pretty small.

That said, that's a really niche use case. Often, as you can see, Python's duck-typing behavior is good enough on its own; if there is no common functionality between the different types, the only meaningful advantages to having the abstract base class are for the developer, not the program itself:

1. Having a common point of reference for the API consumer makes it clear what methods they can expect to have access too
2. For actual ABCs with `@abstractmethod` decorated methods, it provides a definition-time check for subclasses, making it impossible for maintainers to omit a method by accident

Comment: So would you recommend that I do create one because it would make it impossible for me to create an invalid validator? For example, I might create a `ruby_file_validator` that has a typo in one of its method names or something.

Comment: @Ogen: It's mostly personal preference when both interface and implementations are under your control, and used by you. The main reason to create one would be if you were creating an API (for other developers) that required that interface, where defining the interface provides clear expectations that couldn't otherwise be expressed in a concise, checkable way.

Answer (score 2):

Base classes in Python serve to share implementation details and document likenesses. We don't *need* to use a common base class for things that function similarly though, as we use protocols and duck typing. For these validation functions, we might not have a use for a class at all; Java is designed to force people to put everything inside classes, but if all you have in your class is one static method, the class is just noise. Having a common superclass would enable you to check dynamically for that using `isinstance`, but then I'd really wonder why you're handling them in a context where you don't know what they are. For a programmer, the common word in the function name is probably enough.